# Android Studio New Project Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the Android Studio, Installed and when i make a new project i have issues u can see on picture. I try rebuild clean etc... what can i do for work well?[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post the errors here as text.

Comment: Too long, what can i do? :\

Java Compiler error: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: @antal1208 he is asking you to add errors as text in your question. Also update your question with build.gradle file.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild. Yes add the error as a text and also the app gradle file.

Comment: Fixed!! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the gradle path... ...Antal Nándor... wasnt like space and "á" :)
I change the Service directory path(Settings->Build-Gradle) to a space and accent less path.